# Sending large amounts of data from iPhone to a backend service

Tags: ios, rest, http

I have a use case where I need to daily *post* ~600 Mb of json to a backend server that will persist this data. To limit the size I could compress the data with zlib or convert it altogether to avro and then compress it with snappy.
Does this seem like a good practise when it comes to mobile device backend interaction with regards to this much data?

Thank you!

Comment: Reduce the overall size as much as possible. Maybe send less more often. Maybe use something like ["Message pack"](https://msgpack.org/index.html) to further decrease the size. Avoid sending the data over cellular

Answer (score 1):

I think even if you got this down by 10x, it would still be pushing it. At this rate, you'll be running into upload speed issues, bandwidth limits, all kinds of problems. I don't think users are going to be happy with this behavior. Though I suppose that does depend on the use case (which I'm now curious about).

Your backend is going to regularly experience upload failures. Remember networks are unreliable. And, with that much posting, depending on how many instances of your app are out there, could put very high demands on your backend system. If this data is important, you will have to break it up into smaller chunks, at an absolute minimum.

I'd experiment with a few different formats/compression to see how much savings you can get. But, you may also want to throw some brainpower at rethinking the implementation.